# DailyNotificationTrigger in expo-notifications not working on Android device

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo

I am trying to implement notifications in an Expo app using expo-notifications. My trigger object in `scheduleNotificationAsync` conforms to the [`DailyNotificationTrigger`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#dailynotificationtrigger) interface, still I'm getting this error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Failed to schedule the notification. Trigger of type: calendar is not supported on Android.]
```

This is the snippet of code that produces the error:

```
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
  content: {
    title: 'Complete a quiz',
    body: " Don't forget solve a quiz today!",
  },
  trigger: {
    type: 'daily',
    hour: 8,
    minute: 0,
  },
})
```

My target device is an emulator running on Android 10. Please help me identify and fix the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got my hint from interface `DailyTriggerInput`. Working code should be like following:

```js
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
    content: { 
        title: 'Winter is coming!' 
    }, 
    trigger: { 
        hour: 18, minute: 36, repeats: true 
    }
})
```

Comment: For iOS use CalendarNotificationTrigger.

Comment: This does not work from me... ugh

Answer (score 1):

It's not about Daily trigger. Mistake is in a Expo Documentation. It says nothing about Android which not supports calendar. It taken 3 days to me to solve this issue.

So for the next generations, don't use days, hours and minutes in trigger (on Android platform). Just seconds work properly.

Comment: Thanks that did it. And actually I think I will have more flexibility with seconds

Answer (score 0):

Notifications don't work on emulators. You have to run it on your a physical device for notifications to work

Comment: This is local notification, local notification works on emulator!!